# How can you abide by Spotipy's sleep_for_retry() function?

Tags: python, get, google-colaboratory, spotify, spotipy

I have been using spotify's spotipy api and I have been making a lot of requests for artists.  I was at one point looping through 48,000 spotify artists and gathering some information about them.  I realized during that loop, the normal functions had stopped executing and it was stuck on a sleep_for_retry().  I can see the sequence of functions being called in my python notebook and it gets stuck at this:
`artist() > _get() >_internal_call() > request() > send() > send() > urlopen() > sleep() > sleep_for_retry()`

I realize that it was really dumb of me to try to make so many requests and that it was pretty obvious I would get denied at some point.  But going forward, how would I be able to abide by their sleep_for_retry() function?  I have seen some stuff online about using python's time library and doing something like this: `time.sleep(<some amount of time here>)` but I can't figure out how to get that working with my spotipy api.

Does anyone have experience with this?  I love the spotipy API and I would like to keep using it but I don't want to be making more requests than their server can handle.

the error looks like this:

```
--> 321         return self._internal_call("GET", url, payload, kwargs)
    322 
    323     def _post(self, url, args=None, payload=None, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/spotipy/client.py in _internal_call(self, method, url, payload, params)
    262 
    263         try:
--> 264             response = self._session.request(
    265                 method, url, headers=headers, proxies=self.proxies,
    266                 timeout=self.requests_timeout, **args

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    527         }
    528         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 529         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    530 
    531         return resp

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    643 
    644         # Send the request
--> 645         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    646 
    647         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    438         try:
    439             if not chunked:
--> 440                 resp = conn.urlopen(
    441                     method=request.method,
    442                     url=url,

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    874 
    875             response.drain_conn()
--> 876             retries.sleep(response)
    877             log.debug("Retry: %s", url)
    878             return self.urlopen(

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in sleep(self, response)
    426 
    427         if self.respect_retry_after_header and response:
--> 428             slept = self.sleep_for_retry(response)
    429             if slept:
    430                 return

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in sleep_for_retry(self, response)
    405         retry_after = self.get_retry_after(response)
    406         if retry_after:
--> 407             time.sleep(retry_after)
    408             return True
```

I have tried doing this:

```
for i in range(0,5000):
  time.sleep(15)
  currentResults = spotify.artist(uniqueIds[i])
  if (currentResults['popularity'] > 23):
    popularIds2.append(uniqueIds[i])
```

but it still gets stuck with the sleep_for_retry() function

Answer (score 3):

Your issue lies in the way Spotify limits requests to its API.

If you exceed these limits, Spotify will return a 429 status code ("Too Many Requests") and the Retry-After HTTP header, which tells your client how many seconds to wait before trying the next request.

In your case, Spotipy is using the requests library to make HTTP requests, and requests is set up to respect the Retry-After header by default (which is good!). When a 429 status code is returned, the requests library **will automatically retry the request after sleeping for the number of seconds** indicated by the Retry-After header. This is why you're seeing your script hang on the time.sleep(retry_after) line; it's waiting for the Retry-After time to pass.

So I think you get what you want out of the box with default Spotipy configuration.

Comment: Do you know if these limits are documented anywhere. I seem to be getting rate limited using `artist_albums` but `search` seems to be totally fine. It would seem that the rate limits are request specific?